# How to run a remote sed command through ssh if the data includes double quotes ("")?

Tags: ssh, sed, quoting

I'm trying to run through a list of servers and run the next command:

```
itaig@itaig-lt:~$ ssh root@$srvname "sed -i 's/VNCSERVERARGS[6]="-geometry 1920x1080"/VNCSERVERARGS[6]="-geometry 1152x864"/g' /etc/sysconfig/vncservers"
```

I've tried like that as well:

```
itaig@itaig-lt:~$ ssh root@$srvname "sed -i 's/VNCSERVERARGS[6]=\"-geometry 1920x1080\"/VNCSERVERARGS[6]=\"-geometry 1152x864\"/g' /etc/sysconfig/vncservers"
itaig@itaig-lt:~$
```

Both tries gave me a fresh prompt line and when checking the file on the remote machine nothing has changed.
Is that possible to run such a command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think ssh is playing a part in this problem. You should ssh onto onto of the systems and try to run your sed command directly to get it working first then wrap it in an ssh.

I think your match pattern is incorrect you need to escape the `[]` characters and possibly other things too.

Answer (score 2):

In your first attempt, I've highlighted the parts that are double-quoted strings in the local shell. No double quote is ever passed to the remote shell, let alone sed.

```
ssh root@$srvname "sed -i 's/VNCSERVERARGS[6]="-geometry 1920x1080"/VNCSERVERARGS[6]="-geometry 1152x864"/g' /etc/sysconfig/vncservers"
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In your second attempt, this is the remote shell command:

```
sed -i 's/VNCSERVERARGS[6]="-geometry 1920x1080"/VNCSERVERARGS[6]="-geometry 1152x864"/g' /etc/sysconfig/vncservers
```

You got the shell quoting right, but that `[6]` is probably not what you intended: it matches `VNCSERVERARGS6=…` only. If you want to match the brackets literally, you need a backslash before the opening bracket.

```
sed -i 's/VNCSERVERARGS\[6]="-geometry 1920x1080"/VNCSERVERARGS\[6]="-geometry 1152x864"/g' /etc/sysconfig/vncservers
```

In the remote shell, the backslashes are in a single-quoted string and thus interpreted literally. In the local shell, the backslashes are in a double-quoted string; in general they should be doubled, though `\[` in a double-quoted string is interpreted as `\[` anyway.

```
ssh root@$srvname "sed -i 's/VNCSERVERARGS\\[6]=\"-geometry 1920x1080\"/VNCSERVERARGS\\[6]=\"-geometry 1152x864\"/g' /etc/sysconfig/vncservers"
```

Remember that ssh invokes a shell command on the remote side, so you need two levels of quoting: one for the local shell and one for the remote shell. It's usually easier to put single quotes around the remote command and arrange to write that command with no single quote.

```
ssh root@$srvname 'sed -i "s/VNCSERVERARGS\\[6]=\"-geometry 1920x1080\"/VNCSERVERARGS\\[6]=\"-geometry 1152x864\"/g" /etc/sysconfig/vncservers'
```

Alternatively, mount the remote files with [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) and then work on them without having to worry about their being remote.

```
mkdir ~/net/srvname
sshfs root@srvname ~/net/srvname
sed -i 's/VNCSERVERARGS\[6]="-geometry 1920x1080"/VNCSERVERARGS\[6]="-geometry 1152x864"/g' ~/net/srvname/etc/sysconfig/vncservers
```