# Named serial increment SED oneliner

Tags: sed, bind

I need to increment named serial and I want to do it with sed. I've done it like this:

```
echo 2015092315 | gsed s/20[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*/`date +%Y%m%d%H`/g
```

But then I realized that updates to zone file might happen more than once an hour and this above will not be enough.

Now I want to increment the serial by 1. How to do that? I came up with a:

```
gsed 's/20[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*/expr & + 1/e'
```

which does work but it deletes the beginning of line (spaces) and the end of the line (comment), and gives error about a comment (sh: serial: not found) which I do not want.

Comment: A `date` call will usually work, except when the system gets its clock set wrong. I've seen servers boot four years in the future for no apparent reason, for example. I've otherwise moved my DNS over to `nsupdate` related tools, and let the nameserver bump the serial for me.

Comment: any reason you don't want to use `date +%s` in your first gsed?

Comment: @thrig: date will not work for me here because I need to update bind after vm deployment from some interface, which could happen more than once an hour. Didn't thougt about Jeff's idea..

Comment: @JeffSchaller: Thanks for the idea Jeff. I assume I have to restart named servers if I do it like that, since right now 2015092215 is greater than 1443031008, right?

Comment: I would think that a normal reload would do the trick -- the slaves only care that the serial number is higher; I just wanted to point out an alternative. For example, you could add %M to the end of your current solution to add minute-level resolution.

Comment: Break your line into groups so that you can use backreferences e.g. `echo "do   2015092315 #whatever" | sed 's/\(.*\)\(20[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*\)\([^0-9].*\)/echo "\1$(( \2 +1 ))\3"/e'`

Comment: @don_crissti: Thanks don, that's what I was looking for. Now I just have to send that over ssh. But it complains: -bash: \2 +1 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "\2 +1 ")

Comment: @czbg - most likely due to not quoting/escaping properly, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88163

Answer (score 4):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -pe 's/(20[0-9]{3,})/$1+1/e' file
```

Comment: Thanks choroba. I was aware of perl's possibility, but I wanted to do it with sed. So, it isn't possible to achive this part: "$1+1" with sed? I'm thinking now more about Jeff's solution..

Comment: @czbg If it's easier and safer to do it with another tool, then do it with that other tool. `sed` is notoriously bad at doing arithmetics, and you should generally pick the tool that is the best for the job, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the original question and choroba's answer you get following one-liner using GNU `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/(20[0-9]{3,8})(.*$)/echo `expr \1 + 1` "\2"/e'
```

Which can be used like this:

```
[admin@localhost ~]$ echo '2015092315 ; serial' | sed -r 's/(20[0-9]{3,8})(.*$)/echo `expr \1 + 1` "\2"/e'
2015092316  ; serial
```

or on a file:

```
[admin@localhost ~]$ sed -i -r 's/(20[0-9]{3,8})(.*$)/echo `expr \1 + 1` "\2"/e' /path/to/zone_file
```